# django slug works for one word but when it's more than one words it collapses

Tags: python, django

With a small word like "cool" it works but if it's like "not cool" then it doesn't work because slug makes it not-cool.

```
path('<slug>/', views.series_pg, name='series_detail'),
#MODELS.PY    
class Series(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=128, default=1)
    tv_or_movie = models.CharField(max_length=128, default=1)
    period = models.CharField(max_length=128, default=1)
    descritpion = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/%s/" %self.slug

#VIEWS.PY
def series_pg(request, slug):
    series = Series.objects.get(name=slug)
```

If slug changes the original word then it doesn't work

**EDIT:**

My error is

> DoesNotExist at /office/
>   Series matching query does not exist.

I added "The Office" but slug makes it office

Comment: If you initialize a SlugField with something that is not a slug per the [django definition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/glossary/#term-slug), the field will try to generate a slug based on your input.  That's kind of the purpose of this field.  If you want something that just stores text, use TextField or CharField.

Comment: Add `Series` whole model defination.

Comment: @shafik what do you mean? are you saying you want to see Series model?

Comment: yes. Especially `name` property

Comment: @shafik YES done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django slug field works like if you give value `not cool` then it's slugify this to `not-cool`.

In your views.py you want to filter by `name`.
Say in the name it has the value `not cool` but in slugfield, you keep the value `not-cool`. Then you try to filter it out by `.get(name=slug)` that means `.get(not cool=not-cool)`. So the queryset doesn't return any matching object and doesn't match with the URL.

You can do it

```
def series_pg(request, slug):
    series = Series.objects.get(slug=slug)
```

Comment: Thank  you very much I spent so much time on this, so clear now!! thank you

Answer (score 0):

"A slug is a short label for something, containing only letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens. They’re generally used in URLs."

-Django Documentation

What context are you using the Slug Field? It will convert spaces like "not cool" to "not-cool" because that's its purpose.

Comment: my apology if the question wasn't clear, I edited the question.

Comment: Why not use a CharField?

Comment: what do you mean charField? how do i use charfield here?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField

Comment: I dont think you understood the question or you are a noobie like me

Comment: probably later one

Comment: Are you trying to query your model entries based on the url?

Comment: see the other solution here!!